# Android Amplify Cognito Post Confirmation User Table not populating after user is confirmed

Tags: android, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, amazon-dynamodb

**The App**

Android Studio project with Amplify back end that allows the user to sign in and see some profile info. I want to keep a DynamoDB user table that holds some additional data. I expect to update the table depending on some actions the user takes, *however*, I really liked this notion of a Lambda function initially adding the user to the table securely and without me having to do it manually.

**The Problem**

The Lambda function is invoked, but the new user is not added to the generated DynamoDB table. Very frustrating because the only clue I have is a CloudWatch Log (shown below) that I cannot interpret.

I've looked online and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503523/trying-to-use-model-within-post-confirmation-function) SO/GitHub issue, which is fairly similar to mine except I did not `amplify update auth` and set a Post Confirmation trigger there or add any Groups in Cognito. I got no circular dependency error doing `amplify push` commands.

*UPDATE*

I get the same outcome when using the Cognito Hosted UI in my desktop web browser. Surely the Lambda function that Amazon published in their docs isn't flawed?

**What I need**

General guidance on why the user data might not be getting to the DynamoDB table. Should I try to emulate the OP of the linked post above? Is there some intermediate step that I am missing?

Any help is fantastic, and I'm more than happy to provide more resources if they'll help.

Thanks.

**What I've done**

1. `amplify init` and `amplify config`
2. `amplify add auth` following [these](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/android) instructions.
3. In the AWS console I set up the Cognito Hosted UI to let users signup and login. It works great.
4. `amplify add api`following [these](https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/functions/cognito-trigger-lambda-dynamodb/q/platform/android) instructions. Here is the schema.graphql file:

```
type User @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  email: String
}
```

5. `amplify add function` following the same instructions - here is the index.js file:

```
/* Amplify Params - DO NOT EDIT
    API_TBCPAPI_GRAPHQLAPIIDOUTPUT
    API_TBCPAPI_USERTABLE_ARN
    API_TBCPAPI_USERTABLE_NAME
    ENV
    REGION
Amplify Params - DO NOT EDIT */

var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var ddb = new aws.DynamoDB();

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

    let date = new Date();

    if (event.request.userAttributes.sub) {

        let params = {
            Item: {
                'id': {S: event.request.userAttributes.sub},
                '__typename': {S: 'User'},
                'name': {S: event.request.userAttributes.name},
                'email': {S: event.request.userAttributes.email},
                'createdAt': {S: date.toISOString()},
                'updatedAt': {S: date.toISOString()},
            },
            TableName: process.env.API_TBCPAPI_USERTABLE_NAME
        };

        // Call DynamoDB
        try {
            await ddb.putItem(params).promise()
            console.log("Success");
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Error", err);
        }

        console.log("Success: Everything executed correctly");
        context.done(null, event);

    } else {
        // Nothing to do, the user's email ID is unknown
        console.log("Error: Nothing was written to DynamoDB");
        context.done(null, event);
    }
};
```

I was careful to edit the proper DynamoDB table name.

6. `amplify push` with no errors.
7. In the AWS Cognito Console, I manually chose my Post Confirmation Lambda from the drop down list. Saved with no errors.
8. `amplify pull` to make sure I've got the changes (not sure if this was needed).
9. Ran the app, created a user in the Hosted UI, confirmed via email code, logged in, and returned to the app.
10. Went to check the DynamoDB table and there was no entry in the User table. Bummer.
11. Went to check the Lambda monitor, and it showed 1 invocation, with 100% success rate. (I beg to differ)
12. Followed the link to the CloudWatch Logs and found this:

```
2021-05-27T15:47:26.024Z    c6d8ddfc-1f67-4bc9-b01c-1b89b91f0abc    INFO    Error ValidationException: Supplied AttributeValue is empty, must contain exactly one of the supported datatypes
    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18) {
  code: 'ValidationException',
  time: 2021-05-27T15:47:25.983Z,
  requestId: 'BRRPE7CIIAGD1H28DVO7UEGISVVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 22.42081554987443
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `context.done(null, event)` just return the event `return event`.

The issue is when you are using an async function the return value is wrapped in a promise. Without a return your promise resolves to undefined which obviously doesn't pass their validation.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution did not work.

Comment: @JohnBest same error? One of the user attributes is likely undefined then. add `|| ''`  to make sure a string is passed.

Comment: So I do this? ```'id': {S: event.request.userAttributes.sub} || ''```

Comment: I checked the runtime of the lambda it was NodeJs version 14 not 12. I switched to the older version and it works. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: How did you map your API_TBCPAPI_USERTABLE_NAME variable? It has an id and the ENV attached to the table name that I don't want to hard code as an env

Answer (score 1):

The Lambda runtime was set to Node.js 14.x, and I switched it to 12.x to see if that would change anything (maybe the AWS docs were not completely accurate in their instructions).

Anyway that seemed to do it for me, and I got a user loaded into my DynamoDB table.

**Update**

Okay, so it wasn't the Lambda runtime... For some reason if I eliminate the name, email, and dates attributes in the index.js file then it will successfully put the user in the database. I must have made that change, pushed, and THEN changed the runtime.

**Update 2**

Problem is `event.request.userAttributes.name` is empty and a `|| 'no name'` next to it did the trick as suggested in a comment here. The email address actually worked fine.

Honestly, the user id and email are enough for the initial entry. I can add whatever attributes that are necessary later. I'll just use Kotlin and save myself the trouble of trying to debug JavaScript.

Hope this helps someone else trying to navigate [these docs for Android](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/q/integration/android).

Thanks.